# Android - How to open a file with default viewer without knowing file type from my app

Tags: java, android, filepath

I want to open a downloaded file from my app. I know file path in my storage. But dont know File type. As example-

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File("/sdcard/test.mp3");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

This code open a media file, cause I already put file type here -

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
```

Is there any way to open file with it's default viewer without knowing file type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
public void playAudio(File file){
    Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));   
    startActivity(it);  
}
```

This should start every Audio.
I hope this helps you.